# loading menu in the view

Tags: php, codeigniter

my action inside controller looks like this

```
public function index()
{
   $data = array();
   $data['pageTtl'] = "page title test";
   $data['main_menu'] = $this->load->view('_mainMenu');
}
```

on the view

```
<title><?= $pageTitle ?> </title> // works
```

but  `<?php var_dump($main_menu ) ?>` returns null.

file structure is

```
views
     /home/index.php
     _mainMenu.php
```

what I'm doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn’t pass the data value & neither did you return the view as a string(data)

```
$data['main_menu'] = $this->load->view('_mainMenu', '', true);
```

Check the bottom-most section of this page http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/views.html

Answer (score 2):

at your controller use following

```
 $data['main_menu'] = $this->load->view('_mainMenu.php', '', TRUE);
```

and on view page

```
 <?php echo ($main_menu ) ?>
```

that should work.